# Converting array to JSON to check the values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I send an Ajax call to a PHP file, Then an array is returned.

I want to check the values of the returned data.

Here is the Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'num': 12},
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(data){
        JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data.status);
    }
});
```

PHP code:

```
$status = 1;
$msg = 'Test message';
$response = array($status, $msg);
echo json_encode($response);
```

But I'm getting an error `JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character`

Comment: Remove `JSON.parse(data)` from your JS code. jQuery will already have deserialised it for you

Comment: `console.log(data.status);` returns `undefined`

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` output?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It was an incorrect bit of PHP creating the response. Fixed it in my answer after the OP pointed it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `dataType : "json",` in the AJAX parameter list, which tells jQuery to expect JSON and do the Parse internally for you.

So remove the `JSON.parse(data);` and all should be well

You will also have to change the PHP to make the returned data appear in the right place like this

```
$response = array('status' => $status, 'message' => $msg);
```

Comment: But `console.log(data.status);` returns `undefined`

Comment: See amended response from the PHP